# Elasticsearch query existence of field of dictionary

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am having troubles with an exist query in Elasticsearch.
My docuemnts have a inner object (a dictionary mapping strings to float values).

I want to query the inner dictionary for the existance of a specific string and weight the result with the float value that is mapped to that string.

At the moment I was trying

```
  "query": {
     "nested": {
       "path": "words",
       "query": {
         "function_score": {
           "query": {
             "exists": {
               "field": term
             }
           },
           "functions": [
             {
               "field_value_factor": {
                 "field": term
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
  },
```

Where `words` is the dictionary and `term` is the string I am looking for.

This however is not working

```
{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"[nested] nested object under path [words] is not of nested type"}}}]},"status":400}',
```

Does anyone know why?

Edit:

Elasticsearch version: oss 6.1.3.

As for the structure it is more difficult, however it is something like:

```
Doc:
  _id: 1
  words:
    string1: value1
    string2: value2
```

Edit2: Fixed a problem with parenthesis, now the error makes more sense, but still I don't know why it's not working

Comment: provide elastic version you are using and structure of the document itself

Comment: @DevDio You are right, edited